# React-Redux search bar error × "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to create a search bar with React and redux.  I have placed the search bar in one component (clientsearch.js) and the results in another (Clientdevicelocate.js)

I get a 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined' error on the line with the 'location.map'.  It seems like I am not passing an initial state of "".  I am a newbie to Redux and this is my first attempt at passing asynchronous code.

**clientdevicelocate.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import './Clientdevicelocate.css';
import {Table, TableBody, TableHeader, TableHeaderColumn, TableRow, TableRowColumn,} from 'material-ui/Table';

class clientDevicelocate extends Component { 

    render () {
        let locations = this.props.location;  
    console.log('====================================');
    console.log('Locations', locations);
    console.log('====================================');
        return(
            <div>            
                <Table>
                    <TableHeader>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableHeaderColumn>Device Alias</TableHeaderColumn>
                            <TableHeaderColumn>Device Serial Number </TableHeaderColumn>
                            <TableHeaderColumn>Device IMEI</TableHeaderColumn>
                            <TableHeaderColumn>Locate Address</TableHeaderColumn>
                            <TableHeaderColumn>Locate Date</TableHeaderColumn>
                            <TableHeaderColumn>Locate Time</TableHeaderColumn>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHeader>

                    <TableBody>
                    {locations.map(function(location, i){
                        return <TableRow key={location.numVehicleDeviceID}>
                            <TableRowColumn>{location.txtAlias}</TableRowColumn>
                            <TableRowColumn>{location.txtSMSDeviceSN}</TableRowColumn>
                            <TableRowColumn>{location.IMEI}</TableRowColumn>
                            <TableRowColumn>{location.fullAddress}</TableRowColumn>
                            <TableRowColumn>{location.date}</TableRowColumn>
                            <TableRowColumn>{location.time}</TableRowColumn>
                        </TableRow>
                    })}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return{
        loactions: state.locations
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(clientDevicelocate);
```

**clientReducer.js**

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes';

const intialState ={
        client: {
            numClientID:'',
            txtName:''
    }
};

const clientReducer = (state = intialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case actionTypes.SEARCH_CLIENT:
            return{
                ...state, 
                client:{
                    ...state.client,                       
                }
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default clientReducer;
```

**searchClientAction**

I cleared the API call line.  The API works fine and we have been using it in postman and directly in clientdeviceloacte.js prior to moving the code to redux.

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';
import axios from 'axios';


export const setClient = (value) => {
    return{
        type: actionTypes.SEARCH_CLIENT,
        client: value,

    }
};

export const fetchClientFailed = () => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.FETCH_CLIENT_FAILED
    }
}

export const fetchClient = (value) => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://.../.../getDeviceLocation',
            data:   {
                "numClientID" : value,
                "numContactID" : null,
                "ynActive" : true
                }
            })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
            let locations = response.data;
            for(let i=0; i<locations.length; i++){
                let location = locations[i];
                locations[i].fullAddress = location.txtAddress + ', '+ location.txtCity + ', ' + location.txtState + ' ' +location.txtZip;
                locations[i].date = location.dtDate.substring(0,10);
                locations[i].time = location.dtDate.substring(11, 19);
            }
            dispatch(setClient(locations));
            // this.setState({locations: locations});
            })
        .catch ( error => {
                dispatch(fetchClientFailed());
            });
        } 
    };
```

**Clientsearch.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import { setClient} from '../../store/actions/indexAction';

 class SearchBar extends Component {

  render() {
    const {fetchClient,value} = this.props;
    return (
      <input 
        className = 'form-control'
        placeholder = 'Search Client'
        onChange = {(e) => fetchClient(e.target.value)}
        value = {value} />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    value: state.locations
  };

}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return bindActionCreators({setClient}, dispatch);  
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps) (SearchBar);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to pass an empty array in the clientReducer.js in the initialState.

Answer (score 2):

You can try constructing an initial state of an empty array for locations in your clientDevicelocate component.

```
export default class clientDevicelocate extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    this.state = {
      locations:[],
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Same error after adding  :    constructor(props){
        super()
        this.state = {
          locations:[],
        }
      }